# Irregular TTFB and server wait time response

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I've created a custom Wordpress theme from scratch, following the best practices that I could. The site works great most of the time, with a load time that feels okay considering implementation of a lot of frontend stuff (typekit, youtube embed, vimeo, jQuery etc).

The problem is before the frontend resources load. Sometimes I get a Waittime in the server response time that goes up to around 8-10 seconds, while being around 700ms most of the time. This makes it Extremely hard to test and troubleshoot. So the problem either lies in the server settings, or in my php code. Since it's not happening all the time, I think I can conclude that its not the code, since it's the same code running all the time, and therefore should have been slow all the time - but maybe that's a hasty conclusion.

[image]

I'm really looking to get some input on how to further test this, or hear about any experience with irregular server wait time and TTFB.

The website is currently in testmode at wm.minnie.mico.dk

Note: I've been through disabling plugins, but again that should have made it slow ALL the time right?
Also - I'm not caching at the moment, since I need to fix this issue first.

Comment: I would bet on an overloaded web or database server. Do you have server logs?

Comment: that was exactly it - thank you :) the host was punishing the server for having too much memory allocated to it. so even without using it the server got punished for it. i took that memory down from 8gb to 4gb and now everything is fine - such a wierd issue.